# Can't install any gems or update any gem

Tags: rubygems, bundler

I can't do anything with Ruby anymore do the following reason:

```
% gem install multi_json   
Could not find multi_json-1.3.6 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

% bundle install
Could not find multi_json-1.3.6 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

What can I do? Since both commands result same error.

Comment: One solution that I found that worked is comment the whole Gemfile out and install the gems that bundler is crying about.

Comment: Be sure that your `Gemfile` starts with:

    require 'rubygems'

    source 'https://rubygems.org'

then retry to run `bundle install`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to comment out the whole Gemfile and install the gem.

Answer (score 1):

As [you can see](http://rubygems.org/gems/multi_json), that gem is present on rubygems, so check that your `Gemfile` is correct.

It should have this source declaration on top:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```